# jQuery background not displaying in IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, background, w3c-validation

I'm trying to get my website to display the background in IE, however I can't figure out why it's not doing so. I believe it was at some time, for some reason it's not right now.

Some background:
Wordpress website.
Using purchased template - have not heard from them as of yet regarding this problem.
Much customised work on the website so something could have gone wrong.
I'm guessing it's something simple.
Looking for it to work in IE9 as I think the site completely messes up in 8 and below - but if you have tips on how to correct that, that's cool too. 
I've run the CSS through W3 checker, but the code it outputted didn't resolve the issue.

Website: http://www.cardwells.co.nz

Comment: Opening up the IE developer tools I saw a bunch of errors, for example: "HTML1423: Malformed start tag. Attributes should be separated by whitespace. 
www.cardwells.co.nz, line 239 character 79"  You need to address those first to see if they are causing you error.

Answer (score 0):

I debug your code in IE7, IE8 using IE Developer tools.

It threw `Expected identifier, string or number`

The most common cause of this error is missing or extra comma.

In your code

```
$("#logoParade").smoothDivScroll({ 
        autoScrollingMode: "always", 
        autoScrollingDirection: "endlessloopright", 
        autoScrollingStep: 1, 
        autoScrollingInterval: 25, // This comma is not required; Remove this
    });
```

I found extra comma at `autoScrollingInterval: 25,`. Remove that and check again.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. My website doesn't display the slider background in IE, whereas it does in all other browsers.

Comment: @ChadZoghby: Did you check with the above answer ?

Comment: I've removed the comma now, no luck though. : (

Comment: @ChadZoghby: Check updated comment in the answer. The last attribute does not require `,.

Comment: I've removed the comma now. Didn't solve it though. Thanks for your help so far. : )

Edit: Actually, is it working for you?